# what are the use of "|" operator and "<<" operators in c

Tags: c

PINS_DRV_SetPinsDirection(GPIO_PORT, ((1 << LED1) | (1 << LED2)));

here "PINS_DRV_SetPinsDirection" is a function and i am passing arguments which are in (). what is the meaning of those arguments "(GPIO_PORT, ((1 << LED1) | (1 << LED2)))"???

Comment: You don't really need Stackoverflow for questions like that. Try any C language book or guide first.

Comment: i was new to 'C' back then, so no need to be disrespectful.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise or, `<<` is left shift.

Wikipedia has an article on [Operators in C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) which might be worth a look.  It's the first result I got when searching for "c operators" (without the quotes)…